# How to work with IUserType in Automapping Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

i have a custom type that implemented IUserType.
one of my domain classes have a property of this custom type.

now i want to make Automapping work with this domain, it says that "
An association from the table xyz refers to an unmapped class: PersianDate"

PersianDate is my custom type .
how should i tell to automapping that this is not a reference, it is a custom user type that is fitted into a string column !!!

i searched everything that was in the internet , i think there is something wrong here

would you please help me to fix it

Comment: actually it shows errors on all not mapped types in the domain like Image, Point , PointF, SqlType, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer [Here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Available_conventions), i should use a UserTypeConvention in Automapping conventions